# Build FAILED but job status is SUCCESS in Gitlab

Tags: docker, docker-compose, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM mm_php:7.1

ADD ./docker/test/source/entrypoint.sh /work/entrypoint.sh
ADD ./docker/wait-for-it.sh /work/wait-for-it.sh
RUN chmod 755 /work/entrypoint.sh \
    && chmod 755 /work/wait-for-it.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["/work/entrypoint.sh"]
```

entrypoint.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash -e

/work/wait-for-it.sh db:5432 -- echo "PostgreSQL started"

./vendor/bin/parallel-phpunit --pu-cmd="./vendor/bin/phpunit -c phpunit-docker.xml" tests
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '2'
services:

  test:
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        ssh_prv_key: ${ssh_prv_key}
        application_env: ${application_env}
      dockerfile: docker/test/source/Dockerfile
    links:
      - db

  db:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/test/postgres/Dockerfile
    environment:
      PGDATA: /tmp
```

.gitlab-ci.yml:

```
image: docker:latest

services:
  - name: docker:dind
    command: ["--insecure-registry=my.domain:5000 --registry-mirror=http://my.domain"]

before_script:
  - apk add --no-cache py-pip
  - pip install docker-compose
  - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
  - chmod 700 ~/.ssh
  - echo "$SSH_KNOWN_HOSTS" > ~/.ssh/known_hosts
  - chmod 644 ~/.ssh/known_hosts
  - echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" > ~/.ssh/id_rsa
  - chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
  - '[[ -f /.dockerenv ]] && echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config'

test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - export ssh_prv_key="$(cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa)" && export application_env="testing-docker" && docker-compose up --build test
```

All works good. But if tests are failed, status of job in Gitlab is SUCCESS instead of FAILED.

[image]

How to obtain status FAILED if tests are failed?

**UPD**

If I run `docker-compose up` locally, it return no error code:

```
$ export ssh_prv_key="$(cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa)" && export application_env="testing-docker" && docker-compose up --build test
Building db
Step 1/2 : FROM mm_postgres:9.6
...
test_1       | FAILURES!
test_1       | Tests: 1, Assertions: 1, Failures: 1.
test_1       | Success: 2 Fail: 2 Error: 0 Skip: 2 Incomplete: 0
mmadmin_test_1 exited with code 1

$ echo $?
0
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks to me like it's reporting failed on the test without necessarily reporting failure on the return value of the `docker-compose` call. Have you tried capturing the return value of `docker-compose` when tests fail locally?

In order to get `docker-compose` to return the exit code from a specific service, try this:

```
docker-compose up --exit-code-from=service
```

Comment: Thanks! I has updated my answer. Also I has updated `.gitlab-ci.yml`: `docker-compose up --build --exit-code-from=test test` (added option `--exit-code-from`). And it wokrs well now!

Comment: If this doesn't have an issue it just runs forever though :(

Answer (score 2):

When Gitlab CI runs something, if the process executed returns something different from zero, then, your build will fail.

In your case, you are running a docker-compose and this program returns zero when the container finish, what is correct.

You are trying to get phpunit's failure.

I think that is better you split your build in steps and not use docker-compose in this case:

gitlab.yml:

```
stages:
  - build
  - test

build:
  image: docker:latest
  stage: build
  script:
    - docker build -t ${NAME_OF_IMAGE} .
    - docker push ${NAME_OF_IMAGE}

test:
  image: ${NAME_OF_IMAGE}
  stage: test
  script:
    - ./execute_your.sh
```